# Insert a line break in the title of a groupplot plot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

I've seen some posts that address this question for a caption, but most rely on using the caption package...

I have a groupplot that produces the following output:
[image]
Obviously I'd like to clean up those titles and the most straightforward way I can think to do it is by making the titles multi-line.  But how?

Right now the titles are defined with lines like:

```
\nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize ++Resources (Empirical CDF) -- Increasing $\mathbf{\alpha}$},
```

Please comment if it would be useful to upload a full working example...hoping it's a simple answer.

Comment: Something like `title style={text width=7cm}` should do the job (recalled by heart, so you may need to search the TikZ manual for how to apply line breaks in nodes if `text width` was the wrong key)

Comment: Found it.  Replaced the code above with `\nextgroupplot[align=center,title={{\scriptsize +Resources \\ \scriptsize Increasing $\mathbf{\alpha}$}},`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the trick is to use the align key...

```
\nextgroupplot[align=center,title={{\scriptsize +Resources \\ \scriptsize Increasing $\mathbf{\alpha}$}},
```

align can be left, right, or center, but if it is omitted then the \\ is ignored.  There's probably also a more elegant way to get the `\scriptsize` in there, but as I have it if you don't repeat it after the line break it doesn't apply to the second line of the title.